# Sign in by multi-tenant Azure Active Directory in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) I want to use this in my signup user flow.

I created OpenID Connect Identity Provider pointing to the app created in the Azure B2C, and I also created another one pointing to the app created in my normal Azure tenant, and in both cases, when I log in I get the error:

```
AADSTS50020: User account '{<!-- -->{ACCOUNT}}' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/{<;!-- -->{TENANT_ID}}/' does not exist in tenant 'ADefWebserver' and cannot access the application '{<!-- -->{my Azure B2C Tenant id}}'(Blazor Simple Survey AAD) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

Is there documentation that tells what you are supposed to do to fully make this work?

Comment: Which stack are you using? Can you share more details about your question?

Comment: Hi,can the documentation solve your problem?any update?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) business-to-business (B2B) collaboration is a feature within External Identities that lets you invite guest users to collaborate with your organization.

You can add your user account to your tenant 'ADefWebserver' based on the following document.Please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b).